# ESTABLISHED connection recycle after system ip changed

Tags: linux, tcp

System is CentOs

```
sudo netstat -ntp | grep 103.235.244.98
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:61.184.232.47:35650  ::ffff:103.235.244.98:80    ESTABLISHED 41792/java          
tcp        0 268800 ::ffff:61.184.232.47:35651  ::ffff:103.235.244.98:80    ESTABLISHED 41792/java
```

`61.184.232.47` is a ip address obtained by pppoe, and this connection is configured as to re-dail and ip should be changed every 5 min, the problem is the TCP connection on the ip is kept `ESTABLISHED` more than 20min and application will be stuck.

How to configure the system so that this `ESTABLISHED` connection will be found bogus after a reasonable time?

already tried tune `tcp_keepalive_intvl` with  `sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=2` , but seems got no luck.

Comment: `sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established=300` time in seconds for the session to be `INVALID`.  To validate, you can insert a rule to drop or log `INVALID` state.

Comment: `sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try `sysctl -a | grep established`  could be different based on your distro.

Answer (score 0):

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=2` means you want to probe every two seconds but as far as I know this doesn't change the keepalive time itself.

To set te keepalive time to for example 5 minutes you will also have to set the following parameter: `net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 300`

*Also note that procfs needs to be loaded into the kernel and mounted in the filesystem.*